# Javascript - loop through object based on the qty variable

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I asked a similar question earlier (albeit slightly different)..

Basically using the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WTMBA/

I would like to loop through the object and based on the number of qty variable loop through and add the object values to an array.

e.g

```
[Object { url="http://domain.com/abc", qty="1", price="2.99" }, Object { url="http://myurl.com/cde", qty="3", price="64.11" }]
```

The quantify() function should return this as an array with 4 items, as the first item in object has a qty value of 1, and the second value has a quantity of 3 (1+3)

The return array from the quantify function should be structured to include the condition, url & price (see fiddle)

Can anyone suggest how I should edit the quantity function to do this?

Comment: So you want to keep adding the same object to an array based on the qty variable? e.g. qty = 10, add the same item 10 times? If this is the case, try this. http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/apH9H/

Comment: looks good.. will check it out

Comment: If you add that to 'Answer your Q' i'll accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add the same object over and over to an array based on the qty variable of the object you can use nested loops to accomplish this.

```
var products = [{
    url: 'http://domain.com/abc',
    qty: 1,
    price: 2.99
}, {
    url: 'http://myurl.com/cde',
    qty: 3,
    price: 64.11
}];

var i = 0,
    l = products.length,
    cart = [];

for (; i < l; i++) {
    var product = products[i];

    for (var x = 0; x < product.qty; x++)
        cart.push(product);
}
```

Check out the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/apH9H) for a full example.